# Fiddler doesn't capture request from Insomnia but does capture rquest from Postman

Tags: http, post, postman, fiddler, insomnia

Just sending a simple POST request to https://httpbin.org/post.

Fiddler captures the request when I send it from Postman, but doesn't when I send it from Insomnia.

Is there some setting I need to enable either in Fiddler or Insomnia?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, Fiddler changes the system proxy to point to the port it's listening onto, http://localhost:8888. Contrary, Insomnia doesn't use the system proxy, but could be [manually configured to use a specified proxy](https://support.insomnia.rest/article/53-http-s-proxy):

- Choose <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>HTTP Proxy</kbd> and set `http://localhost:8888` (or whatever Fiddler is using).

Comment: Thanks.  In Insomnia preferences I have 'Enable proxy' checked in the HTTP Network Proxy section of the General tab.  I then have a URL in the HTTPS Proxy text box which includes my corporate proxy address; prior to adding this I was unable to send requests to the external API I was targeting.  Can I have both this proxy and the fiddler proxy set up simultaneously?  Thanks again.

Comment: Fiddler is basically a proxy itself, so it should be put between Insomnia and the corporate proxy. By default, on startup Fiddler detects the system proxy (in your case this should be your corporate proxy) and "chains" to it.
So basically you should: just set the proxy in Insomnia to point to Fiddler, and then Fiddler will automatically detect and use the system proxy. If the detection doesn't work for some reason (there are a lot of different possible setups), you may need to tweak Tools -> Options -> Gateway in Fiddler to ensure it's using the corporate proxy.

Comment: Thanks!  Will try this.